# Wifi connection works inspite of access point

Tags: android, wifi, captivenetwork

I have a code that tests if a wifi connection is available.

```
public boolean checkInternetConnection() {

ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
        urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
        urlc.setReadTimeout(4000);
        urlc.connect();
        if (urlc.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Internet connection is OK");
            return true;
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
              mue.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ie) {
              ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "No internet connection.");
    return false;
}
```

To access the internet, I have to through an access point, this is why I espacially ping google because I need if we are also logged in. I have noticed that in many cases, eventhough I do not log into the captive portal, the code sill reaches google and returns true. I am also able to internet servers, such as ftp. 
Does anyone know what is the cause of this behavior ? Has anyone else noticed this behavior ?

Thank you,

Comment: I do not see you pinging google. Nor a login. Nor a captive portal. Whatever that would be.

Answer (score 0):

Some captive portals allow access without logging in to a limited set of services (e.g. company corporative website of the owner of the WiFi service). I've seen Google front page allowed in some WiFi APs I've used over the years. That may be what you've noticed.

Maybe a better approach (or additional) would be to check network detailed state [NetworkInfo.html#getDetailedState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#getDetailedState()) which also gives you information about captive portal detection.

Also, checking a specific page in your own servers may help (is less likely to be allowed without logging in), plus doing it through HTTPS instead of plain HTTP may give you additional information (is quite common to get a certificate not matching error because captive portals act like a man-in-the-middle).

Comment: I added NetworkInfo.html#getDetailedState() in the code above. I tried without logging into the portal and  I got the state CONNECTED and the chechInternet function returned true. Though, this time, I was not able to reach the foreign server, though it sometimes works (which is not one my servers, I do not have any). I the  tried after loging into the portal and I got the same answer CONNECTED.

Comment: On second review of your code, you're not really checking that you reach google.com. You're just checking that you get a page with a 200 Ok, but you don't know if this page is really google.com or the captive portal. If you change the URL to https://www.google.com (as I already said in my answer) you will likely get a certificate error, that will allow you to check the connectivity more accurately.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I tried switching URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com"); to URL url = new URL("google.com"); and I got java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: google.com but I think I misunderstood what you asked.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that the URL has been changed to a link. I meant `https://www.google.com` (e.g. changing the URL from HTTP to HTTPS).

Comment: I switch to https ans got an error : javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname www.google.com not verified: I had this error either I am logged in or not.

Comment: At the same time I added the code below : `InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     if (!url.getHost().equals(urlConnection.getURL().getHost())) {
       // we were redirected! 
     }` and though NOT logged in, I did not pass inside the if, and could reach the extern server (If I open chrome and type a request, I only get the "non connection error).

Comment: Usually there's no redirect, you get the captive portal for any URL, like this was the content of that URL (hence somehow temporarily hijacks all the connections). That's why you get the `SSLPeerUnverifiedException`, because if you use SSL the certificate doesn't match (you usually get a generic or a self-signed certificate). So, the exception is expected when you're in a captive portal (that's why I suggested using HTTPS). The reason you're also getting after logging in too may be because of caching (try to log in and then start the app after a Force stop, this would prove it).